# How to access jakarta validation constraints default messages?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, javabeans

Using Jakarta Been Validation https://hibernate.org/validator/ to validate Java code, I annotate a Classes property by a default @NotEmpty validation anotaton

```
@Validate
public class A {
..
@NotEmpty
private List<String> myList;
..
}
```

In a Test I set myList to an empty List, validate that List and expect the violation "must not be empty", which is the default violation message for the standard @NotEmpty annotation. I found that by printing it, but also here https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/resources/org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages.properties

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<A>> violations = validator.validate(A);

assertThat(violations).anyMatch(having Message("must not be empty", A.class));
```

This works, but I would like to replace the expected Message string with a reference to the default-string like jakarta.validation.constraints.Null.message, avoiding duplication of Strings. This however does not work:

```
assertThat(violations).anyMatch(having Message(jakarta.validation.constraints.Null.message, A.class));
```

Is there any validation expert around, that can show me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

one has to load it from the **classpath**, if provided by **`/ValidationMessages.properties`** (or language specific `ValidationMessages_<x>(_<y>).properties`):

```
Properties ps = new Properties() ;
ps.load( getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ValidationMessages.properties") ) ;

assertThat(violations).anyMatch(having Message( 
  ps.getProperty( "jakarta.validation.constraints.Null.message"),
  A.class))
```

if provided/overridden by direct **class annotation**, one has to **use reflection on the specific classes field or method and get its annotation**.